# Select2 tagging input loses value AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2

I have an app that switches views with `ng-switch`, while switching views my tagging input specifically loses its value and falls into its object string, none of my other inputs suffer this issue:

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<input ui-select2="version2" 
        id="keywordsGlobal" 
        name="keywordsGlobal" 
        class="region-keywords input-xlarge" 
        data-ng-model="data.keywordsGlobal" 
        required-multiple />
```

**JSON:**

```
[  
   {  
      "id":"[object Object]",
      "text":"[object Object]"
   }
]
```

Is there any way to prevent this specifically?

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr or similar example? You may need to set a watch condition or function to be applied before your switch happens, to specifically set the value of the input back to your scope - seems like the plugin is changing it into something Angular doesn't like?

Comment: exactly, select2 can only see the string values of the tagging input, but are stored as an array of objects - it loses its value when switching between views with ng-switch - I will post plnkr

Comment: Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/whiteb0x/qdrjk/ the input in question is in Step 2, notice if you cycle through the steps the value changes to the object string - has me baffled!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data didn't appear to be loaded correctly on subsequent loading of the select. Using `initSelect()` and manually re-assigning the data to the select appears to fix the issue.

Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/qdrjk/111/

```
$scope.version2 = {
    tags : null,
    initSelection: function(elem, callback) {
        console.log(elem);
        var data = $scope.data.keywordsGlobal;
        callback(data);
    },
    createSearchChoice : function(term, data) {
        if ($(data).filter(function() {
            return this.text.localeCompare(term) === 0;
        }).length === 0) {
            return {
                id : term,
                text : term
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oh man I must have been so close, thank you. I have one last standing question for this app - please stay tuned for some easy points ;)

Comment: @Alex Your fiddle isn't working now as the link to the AngularUI.js resource is broken. Working link: http://jsfiddle.net/qdrjk/111/

Comment: Hopefully whiteb0x can, the fiddle was based on his code so I don't have a copy. Also must have been specifically removed by someone?

Answer (score 4):

I had all kinds of problems with ui-select2, and just wrote a simple custom directive and everything worked.  If anyone else is running into problems with angular, select2, and tagging, I'd recommend giving it a try.  What worked for me is a template like:

```
<input type="text" tag-list ng-model="item.tags">
```

Note that item.tags is a javascript array, not a string of comma separated tags or anything like that.  Used with a custom directive (that doesn't use ui-select2, just select2):

```
app.directive('tagList', function($timeout) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(value) {
        if (value !== undefined) {
          element.select2('val', value);
        }
      });

      element.bind('change', function() {
        var value = element.select2('val');
        controller.$setViewValue(value);
      });

      $timeout(function() {
        element.select2({
          tags: []
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: This is perfect for what I've been trying to do on a couple different projects. For one, I need this exactly, but for what I'm doing now, how can I modify this to lock the list to a specific set of tags that are stored under a model? I'm having a hard time doing that

Comment: Thank you so much Dan , this is just what I wanted. survived from geeting into trouble of ui-select2...