# How can I determine when ng-options has finished updating the DOM?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to implement the jQuery multiselect plugin using a directive inside my app. Here' the select element:

```
<select multiple 
        ng-model="data.partyIds" 
        ng-options="party.id as party.name for party in parties" 
        xs-multiselect="parties">
</select>
```

The model `parties` model is loaded through $http. The multiselect plugin parses the `option` elements inside the `select` and generates the nice multi select.

Is there a way to detect when the `select` element is populated with options so I can tell the multiselect plugin to update its data?

Here's my directive:

```
machineXs.directive("xsMultiselect", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            element.multiselect().multiselectfilter();
            scope.$watch(scope[attrs["xsMultiselect"]], function() {
                // I tried watching but it doesn't help
                element.multiselect('refresh');
                element.multiselectfilter("updateCache");
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Inside your $watch, try calling $timeout -- i.e., put the multiselect stuff inside a timeout callback function.  This might give the ng-options directive a chance to run and add the options to the DOM.

Comment: It's not working. Did I correctly set the $watch?

Comment: It looks okay to me.  I wasn't sure if my suggestion would work.  Angular doesn't really have any way to signal when rendering is complete.  Sometimes $timeout works, but not always.

Comment: These might give you some ideas: Lucas wraps `chosen` in a directive: [blog post](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-chosen-plugin-awesome/);  whiteb0x wraps `select2` in a directive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212530/select2-tagging-input-loses-value-angularjs

Comment: Yes, the AngularJS UI select2 directive is something worth considering. If I don't find something soon I will have to implement something similar to that.

Comment: Looking at this again, the $watch should instead be `scope.$watch(attrs.xsMultiselect, ...)`

Comment: Yes, this works. I thought I had to watch the reference not the scope property name :) But how "safe" is it? Will it work the same way if the select has 400 options?

Comment: Is it working with the $timeout, or without it?  Regarding "safe", I would assume that ngOptions does all of its DOM modification at once, but I'm only guessing here.

Comment: I didn't try without $timeout yet.

Comment: Well, for a few entries inside the select it seems to work just fine without $timeout there. I'll do some tests with more values today/tomorrow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, use

```
scope.$watch(attrs.xsMultiselect, ...)
```

I'm not sure when the watch triggers vs when ngOptions updates the DOM.  If you find that the watch is triggering too early, you can try using [$evalAsync()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24evalAsync) or $timeout().  $evalAsync will execute later, but before the DOM renders.  $timeout() will execute later, after the DOM renders.

```
scope.$watch(attrs.xsMultiselect, function() {
   scope.$evalAsync(function() {
      element.multiselect('refresh');
      element.multiselectfilter("updateCache");
   });
});
```

or, after the DOM renders:

```
scope.$watch(attrs.xsMultiselect, function() {
   $timeout(function() {
      element.multiselect('refresh');
      element.multiselectfilter("updateCache");
   });
});
```

Comment: This is not working in Angular 1.5.6, it fires prior to the DOM being updated. Any ideas?!